# java fx imageslideshow using animations

Tags: java, javafx

i'm trying to make simple slideshow using java fx. I'm implementing methods which allow me after pressing button to show one image after another until list is over.
For now i have a code like this...it works but it shows images too fast i dont know why.Maybe someone can help me and tell me how can i slow down this timeline variable or timer.thanks in advance:

```
package pl.gallery.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import pl.gallery.model.ImageParser;

public class MainPaneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;

@FXML
private Button nextButton;

@FXML
private MenuBar menuBar;

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPaneTop;

@FXML
private HBox hBox;

@FXML
private Button previousButton;

@FXML
private MenuItem openFolder;

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPaneCenter;

@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

@FXML
private Button slideShowButton;

@FXML
private Menu menu;

private Image image;

private ImageParser parser;

private ObservableList<Image> imagesList;
private int indexPrev = 0;
private int indexNext = 0;
private Timeline timeline;
private AnimationTimer timer;

//variable for storing actual frame
private Integer i=0;
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
        throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    parser = new ImageParser();
    imagesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();

    openFolder.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            /*
             * parser = new ImageParser(); imagesList = new
             * ArrayList<Image>(); DirectoryChooser dc = new
             * DirectoryChooser(); File dir = dc.showDialog(new Stage());
             * parser.createFileList(dir);
             * 
             * 
             * imagesList.add(new Image(parser.getFilesList().get(0)
             * .toURI().toString())); imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(0));
             */

            File dir = dc.showDialog(new Stage());
            imagesList = parser.createImagesListFromFileList(dir);
            imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(0));

        }
    });


    slideShowButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


            timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
            Duration duration = new Duration(1000);
            timeline.setDelay(duration);
            timer = new AnimationTimer() {
                @Override
                public void handle(long l) {
                    imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(i));

                    i++;
                }

            };
            timeline.play();
            timer.start();
             }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Use a `Timeline`, not an `AnimationTimer`. Add a `KeyFrame` with an `EventHandler` to the `Timeline`.

Comment: @James_D thank you very much, it works!! i'm trying to add fading transition efect to each image, you think it's possible to do within timeline code? here's my code for now of this method:

Comment: slideShowButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

   Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

    KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
      new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

       @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        if (i < imagesList.size()) {
         imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(i));
         i++;
        }

       }

      });
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
    timeline.play();

Comment: so i need to invoke timeline after fadetransition of first image ends(so i need to use setonfinished of the fadetransition) am i right?

Comment: Please edit your question (or post a new one, if it is a new question), instead of posting code in comments. (It's unreadable there.)

Comment: @James_D sorry James, i've made another question . thanks in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798493/java-fx-using-fade-and-timeline-transition