# java fx using fade and timeline transition

Tags: java, javafx

i want to make image slide show with fade and timeline transitions, so when i press the button one image dissapear(by fade animation) and another will be appearing(by fade and timeline transition).For now i have a code like this which makes only first image dissapearing and then only timeline works...(im using parallel transition, i also tried sequential but it doesn't work) .

```
public class MainPaneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;

@FXML
private MenuBar menuBar;

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPaneTop;

@FXML
private HBox hBox;

@FXML
private MenuItem openFolder;

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPaneCenter;

@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

@FXML
private Button slideShowButton;

@FXML
private Menu menu;

private Image image;

private ImageParser parser;

private ObservableList<Image> imagesList;
private int indexPrev = 0;
private int indexNext = 0;
private Timeline timeline;
private AnimationTimer timer;
int i = 0;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
        throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    parser = new ImageParser();
    imagesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();

    openFolder.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            File dir = dc.showDialog(new Stage());
            imagesList = parser.createImagesListFromFileList(dir);
            imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(0));

        }
    });
    slideShowButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition();

            ft.setNode(imageView);
            ft.setDuration(new Duration(2000));
            ft.setFromValue(1.0);
            ft.setToValue(0.0);
            ft.setCycleCount(imagesList.size());
            ft.setAutoReverse(true);

            imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(0));

            timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

            KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                            if (i < imagesList.size()) {
                                imageView.setImage(imagesList.get(i));
                                i++;
                            }

                        }

                    });
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);

            ParallelTransition parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition();
            parallelTransition.getChildren().addAll(
                    ft,
                   timeline
            );
            parallelTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            parallelTransition.play();


        }
    });
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a single `Timeline` for this. For example, for a 250ms fade in, 250ms fade out, and a new image every second, you want the following `KeyFrame`s:

- Time 0: Opacity 0.0
- Time 0.25 seconds: Opacity 1.0
- Time 0.75 seconds: Opacity 1.0
- Time 1.0 seconds Opacity 0.0 and load new image.

You can do this with

```
timeline = new Timeline();

KeyValue transparent = new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 0.0);
KeyValue opaque = new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 1.0);

KeyFrame startFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, transparent);
KeyFrame endFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250), opaque);
KeyFrame startFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(750), opaque);
KeyFrame endFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {
    if (i < images.size()) {
        imageView.setImage(images.get(i));
        i++ ;
    }
}, transparent);

timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(startFadeIn, endFadeIn, startFadeOut, endFadeOut);

timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Comment: thank you very much James_D it works, but first image is fading twice so im working to fix this.thanks again regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the previous answer that addresses the issue raised in the previous answer's comment.

The following fades in the first image over 250 milliseconds, then displays it at 100% opacity for the next 500 milliseconds, the fades it out over the next 250 milliseconds.  The first `KeyFrame` loads the initial image and the last `KeyFrame` removes the image (by setting it to null).  When the animation is over, the `Timeline`'s `OnFinished()` method is called which checks to see if there are more images and, if there are, calls `displayNextMedia()`, which starts the process all over again.  Note that calling `displayNextImage()` from within `Timeline`'s `OnFinished()` event handler does not cause recursion into `displayNextImage()`.

```
//The Application's onStart() method calls the local method displayNextImage()
//images is some collection that implements getNext() and isEmpty()

void displayNextImage() {
timeline = new Timeline();

KeyValue transparent  = new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 0.0);
KeyValue opaque       = new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 1.0);

KeyFrame startFadeIn  = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {imageView.setImage(images.getNext());}, transparent);
KeyFrame endFadeIn    = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250), opaque);
KeyFrame startFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(750), opaque);
KeyFrame endFadeOut   = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {imageView.setImage(null);}, transparent);

timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(startFadeIn, endFadeIn, startFadeOut, endFadeOut);
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);


timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (!images.isEmpty()) {
          displayNextImage();
        }
    }
});

timeline.play();
}
```